# Oakum vs fibreglass insulation

Tags: insulation, weatherstripping

I am building a cabin and would like to place some extra form of insulation to pair with the chinking of the logs.  I have seen traditional builds on the internet which use tarred oakum between the foundation and base log, as well as, between each log.  The reason given is that if the oakum gets wet, it expands while keeping the same insulation properties.  Does fibreglass insulation have the same property? Is there any benefit that tar oakum would provide to a cabin that fibreglass insulation would not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that fibreglass insualtion does not retain its insulation properties when wet and is inferior for my given application of weatherizing a cabin.  Tar oakum expands when wet and continues to produce a wind/weather barrier therefore it is a good option for outside facing insulation.